# ViewPager with fragments: getActivity returns null onResume after swipe

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have ViewPager with 2 different fragments, and when swiping between in my `onResume` method `getActivity()` returns always `null`.

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public static final int PAGE_RECORD = 0;
    public static final int PAGE_CAPTURE = 1;
    public static final int PAGE_PICK = 2;
    private Context context;

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context) {
        super(fm);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int type) {

        switch(type){
            case 0:
                return new RecordFragment();
            case 1:
                return new CaptureFragment();
        }

        return new Fragment();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pager_adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), this);
        pager.setAdapter(pager_adapter);

        OnPageChangeListener pageChangeListener = new OnPageChangeListener() {

            int currentPosition = 0;

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int newPosition) {

                FragmentLifecycle fragmentToShow = (FragmentLifecycle)pager_adapter.getItem(newPosition);
                fragmentToShow.onResumeFragment();

                FragmentLifecycle fragmentToHide = (FragmentLifecycle)pager_adapter.getItem(currentPosition);
                fragmentToHide.onPauseFragment();

                currentPosition = newPosition;
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) { }

            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) { }
        };

        pager.setOnPageChangeListener(pageChangeListener);
```

and

```
public class CaptureFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener, FragmentLifecycle {

    private static final String TAG = "CaptureFragment";
    private ResizableCameraPreview mPreview;
    private RelativeLayout mLayout;
    private int camera_id = 0;
    private ImageButton record_btn;
    private ImageView flash_btn;
    public ImageView done_btn;
    private ImageView rotate_camera;
    private ImageView delete_btn;
    private TextView text;


    public CaptureFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        MainGifActivity.capture_fragment = this;
        setRetainInstance(true);
        Log.i(TAG, "onAttach");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreate");
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Log.i(TAG, "onCreateView");
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_record, null);

        mLayout = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.layout);
        text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.count_text);
        text.setText(""
                + (TakenPictures.FRAMES_COUNT - TakenPictures.photos.size()));

        delete_btn = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.delete);
        done_btn = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.done_btn);
        record_btn = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.record_btn);
        rotate_camera = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.rotate_btn);
        flash_btn = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.flash_btn);

        delete_btn.setOnClickListener(this);
        record_btn.setOnClickListener(this);
        flash_btn.setOnClickListener(this);
        done_btn.setOnClickListener(this);
        rotate_camera.setOnClickListener(this);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.i(TAG, "onResume " + getActivity()); //null

    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Log.i(TAG, "onPause");
        if(mPreview == null)
            return;
        mPreview.isPause = true;
        mPreview.stop();
        mLayout.removeView(mPreview);
        mPreview = null;
    }


    public void forcePause(){
        mPreview.isPause = true;
        mPreview.stop();
        mLayout.removeView(mPreview);
        mPreview = null;
    }

    private void createCameraPreview() {
        mPreview = new ResizableCameraPreview(MainGifActivity.capture_fragment.getActivity(), camera_id,
                CameraPreview.LayoutMode.FitToParent, false, mLayout, 1, done_btn);
        LayoutParams previewLayoutParams = new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        previewLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        mLayout.addView(mPreview, 0, previewLayoutParams);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.done_btn:

            if (TakenPictures.photos.size() == 0)
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No frames recorded",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            else {
                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), EditGifActivity.class));
                getActivity().finish();
            }
            mPreview.isRecording = false;
            mPreview.isInterrupted = true;
            break;

        case R.id.record_btn:

            synchronized (mPreview) {
                if (mPreview == null)
                    return;
                if (mPreview.isRecording) {
                    if (mPreview.isPause) {
                        if (mPreview.isOutOfMemory) {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                                    "Is out of memory, please click done",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                        }
                        mPreview.isPause = false;
                    } else
                        mPreview.isPause = true;
                } else {
                    mPreview.isRecording = true;
                    // TimeCounterTask time_counter = new TimeCounterTask();
                    // time_counter.execute(System.currentTimeMillis());
                }
            }
            break;

        case R.id.rotate_btn:

            boolean did_r = false;
            boolean did_p = false;
            if (mPreview.isRecording)
                did_r = true;
            if (mPreview.isPause)
                did_p = true;

            synchronized (mPreview.mCamera) {
                mPreview.isRotated = true;
                camera_id = ((camera_id == 0) ? 1 : 0);
                mPreview.stop();
                mLayout.removeView(mPreview);
                createCameraPreview();

                mPreview.isRecording = did_r;
                mPreview.isPause = did_p;
            }
            break;

        case R.id.flash_btn:

            mPreview.turnFlash();
            break;

        case R.id.delete:
            synchronized (TakenPictures.photos) {
                TakenPictures.photos.clear();
            }
            text.setText("Time: "
                    + ((TakenPictures.FRAMES_COUNT - TakenPictures.photos
                            .size())));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPauseFragment() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onPauseFragment()");
        //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "onPauseFragment():" + TAG, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
    }

    @Override
    public void onResumeFragment() {
        onResume();

        getActivity(); // always null

        //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "onResumeFragment():" + TAG, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Please help me to find how to get activity after swiping;

Comment: The fragments are displayed correctly otherwise?

Comment: Yes, they are, until i want to use context..

Comment: I don't kown if that would solve the problem, but `onResumeFragment` should call call through to the super-class.

Comment: can you please show where you set up the viewpager in the activity?

Answer (score 0):

You could use your global "context" variable and probably cast it to your main activity. You set the context in the class constructor so why not using it instead of getActivitiy()?

Answer (score 0):

Declare a global activity like this:

```
YourActivityName activity;    
     @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {            
           activity = (YourActivityName) getActivity();       
        }
```

then you can use variable `activity` where ever you want and it will not be null.